# `npm` error as `Error: Cannot find module` - how to fix

Tags: node.js, npm

In my application, when i try to call the service I am getting the error as like this:

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/api/sessions'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Tutorials\try\ModernWebApp\server.js:13:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
 [14:38:53] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

here is my `server.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var app = express();

app.use(express.static( __dirname + '/assets'))

app.use(express.static( __dirname + '/templates'))

app.use(bodyParser.json());
//if i remove both this 2 lines, no issues come.
app.use(require('/api/sessions', require( __dirname + '/controllers/api/sessions')));
app.use(require('/api/users', require('./controllers/api/users')));



app.get('/', function( req, res ){
    res.sendFile( __dirname + '/layouts/app.html');
})

app.listen( 8888,  function(){
    console.log('app listening!' + 8888 );
})
```

what is wrong here, how to solve this. the 2 files are nothing but to handling the query from front end.

`session.js` for sample:

```
var router      = require('express').Router();
var bcrypt      = require('bcryptjs');
var jwt         = require('jwt-simple');
var User        = require('../../models/user');
var config      = require('../../config');


router.post('/sessions', function( req, res, next ) {

    User.findOne({
        username: req.body.username,
    }).select('password').select('username')
    .exec(function( err, user ) {
        if( err ) { return next( err )}

        if(!user) { return res.send(401)}

        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, function( err, valid ) {

            if( err ) { return next( err )}

            if(!valid) { return res.send(401)}

            var token = jwt.encode({username:user.username}, config.secret);

            res.send( token );

        })


    })

});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using just.

```
app.use(require('/api/sessions'));
app.use(require('/api/users'));
```

If that doesn't work give the proper path of the module you want to require.Because require function only take one parameter that is a module ID in string.

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_require_id

Answer (score 1):

you just use `require('/api/sessions')`, so node will look for `sessions.js` file in your `root dir(/)` not your work directory.

maybe you should try `require('./api/sessions')`